# Android Unit Tests failing for Debug build type

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

My Unit tests are failing with Method d in android.util.Log not mocked but only when I run testDebug.
If running testRelease all is fine and they correctly pass.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
Same thing happens when running gradle from console and Android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  is an explanation how I solved this for future reference. 
Problem with tests working in debug but not release were due to a fact that Log.d (and friends from android framework) were not correctly  mocked.
Reason  for it working when built as release is that our loging was conditional based on this property from build config. Basically we have if (BuildConfig.type!="Release") Log.d (...) and since the compiler removes this block due to final value it doesn't  get called when testing  release.
To mock static method Log.d I used PowerMock. Mocking  was easy  but setting up Power Mock is really a hassle so there might probably  be beter ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ["Method ... not mocked"](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-) link on Android Studio Project Site.
It says:

> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito). If that proves problematic, you can add the snippet below to your build.gradle to change this behaviour:

```
build.gradle
  android {
     // ...
     testOptions {
         unitTests.returnDefaultValues ​​= true
     }
 }
```

> We are aware that the default behavior is problematic when using classes like Log or TextUtils and will evaluate possible solutions in future releases.

I just used the above to get rid of the exception for now.